# How to pass a variable to onclick function of a dynamically created button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating buttons dynamically (using html content as string). I need to pass a variable to the onclick function of the button. Below is my code.

```
yesBtnLbl = 'FM-001-001-017';         // This value will change dynamically. I can't hardcode.
yesStepIntent = 'FM-001-001-017';     // This value will change dynamically. I can't hardcode.
control = 
    '<button class="gray-button" onclick="diagBtnClick(' + yesStepIntent + `)">${yesBtnLbl}</button>`;
```

The button is displaying properly with the text 'FM-001-001-017'. But when I click the button, I am getting below error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: FM is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)
```

I tried with below code also but same error is getting thrown when I click the button.

```
control =
        `<button class="gray-button" onclick="diagBtnClick(${yesStepIntent})">${yesBtnLbl}</button>`;
```

But if I directly place the value inside the onclick function as below, it is working.

```
control = 
        `<button class="gray-button" onclick="diagBtnClick('FM-001-001-017')">${yesBtnLbl}</button>`
```

But I can't hardcode the value as this will be generated at run time. Can some one please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: It's because you're not putting the quotes in which are needed to construct a JS string literal. However I would advise you not to fix it that way, but to use `addEventListener` to add an actual function, and write this as proper JS rather than having to faff with constructing strings of JS code.

Comment: Oh. Thanks Robin. I missed the quotes.